# Python: How do I split a value in column using regex and keep the right side?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to clean up a column in my data frame that has the count next to size (ex: 12X350). I'm trying to only get the right side of the X which is the size. But having some issues.

```
import pandas as pd 
data = [['product1', '13X255'], ['product2', "2"], ['product3', "500"]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Product', 'Size'])  
df 

    Product     Size
0   product1    13X255
1   product2    2
2   product3    500
```

Using this string split with regex gets at what I need but fills in values with

```
df['Size'].str.split(r'[A-Z]', n =1, expand = True)
    0   1
0   13  255
1   2   None
2   500 None
```

Desired output that I would like to have:

```
    Product     Size
0   product1    255
1   product2    2
2   product3    500
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what do you want to see?

Comment: is the separation always `X`, then maybe `df['Size'].str.split('X').str[-1]`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: so yuio want columm to be 255, 2, 500 ? that is matching `\d+$` gets that info. many ways to set it even by manipulating _data_ container

Comment: Try `df['Size'].str.extract(r'X(?P<Size>\d+)', expand=True).fillna("")`

Comment: Added the desired output at the bottom for clarity.

Comment: could you check my solution : `df['Size'] = df['Size'].str.split(r'[A-Z]', n=1).str[-1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['Size'] = df['Size'].str.split(r'[A-Z]', n=1).str[-1]
#if neccessary astype(str)
#df['Size'] = df['Size'].astype(str).str.split(r'[A-Z]', n=1).str[-1]
```

or

```
df['Size'] = df['Size'].str.split(r'[A-Z]', n=1, expand = True).ffill(axis=1)[1]
```

---

```
print(df)
    Product Size
0  product1  255
1  product2    2
2  product3  500
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
df['Right Side Of X'] = df['Size'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$', expand=False).fillna("")
```

The `(\d+)$` expression will capture one or more digits at the end of string. `.fillna("")` will populate non-matches with empty strings.

Comment: This gets me the 255 for product 1 but gives me blanks for products 2 & 3. I'd like to keep those values.

Please see bottom of question where I give desired output.

Comment: @Sizzling_Boots Fixed

Comment: that definitely works now. I'm guessing there's quite a few ways to solve this. My dataset isn't super intensive on size but is there a performance element to any of solutions given or just choose the one that works for you?

Comment: @Sizzling_Boots I think performance will not be impacted much if the strings are short. The `(\d+)$` pattern is not super-efficient as it checks for one or more digits first and then checks for end of string. A better regex will be `r'^(?:.*\D)?(\d+)$'`.